# Java "identifier expected" error

Tags: java, identifier

I have the following code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sorts {
    public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<Car>) {
        Comparator compareThing = new CarNameComparator();
        int min;
        Car temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size() - 1; i++){
            min = i;
            for(int j = min+1; j < objects.size(); j++){
                if(compareThing.compare(objects.get(i), objects.get(j))> 0){
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            temp = (Car)objects.get(i);
            objects.set(i, objects.get(min));
            objects.set(min, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

and my IDE highlights the close parenthesis at the end of line 3, saying "expected identifier."

I can't tell what it means. This is a static method so it won't have a type, and it's not referring to the comparator because that has an identifier. What should I do?

Comment: `sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<Car> obj)`.

Comment: Your `Comparator` doesn't have a name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<Car> identifier)
```

You missed the argument name in the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But you have to specify an identifier for the passed parameter of the type Comparator. I guess what you want to do is:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList objects, CarNameComparator compareThing) {
    int min;
    Object temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size() - 1; i++){
        min = i;

        for(int j = min+1; j < objects.size(); j++){
            if(compareThing.compare(objects.get(i), objects.get(j))> 0){
                min = j;
            }
        }

        temp = (Object)objects.get(i);
        objects.set(i, objects.get(min));
        objects.set(min, temp);
    }
}
```

Or you might just want to remove the parameter at all and do something like:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList objects) {
    Comparator compareThing = new CarNameComparator();

    int min;
    Object temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size() - 1; i++){
        min = i;

        for(int j = min+1; j < objects.size(); j++){
            if(compareThing.compare(objects.get(i), objects.get(j))> 0){
                min = j;
            }
        }

        temp = (Object)objects.get(i);
        objects.set(i, objects.get(min));
        objects.set(min, temp);
    }
}
```

If you could specify your problem more specific, a better answer may be possible.

Comment: I'm marking the other answer as the "correct answer" for it's brevity, but thank you for the lengthy response. You're right, I just forgot to give my comparator object a name. The reason I take it as an argument instead of creating it like you suggested is that I have two different comparator objects that sort by different attributes. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome :)